# Can we tab on TabIndex only without TabStop

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an UI who have a lot of object. I want my tab to circle between some object.

With

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"
```

But i don't want to stop on some object without TabIndex.

I know i can use

```
TabStop="False"
```

But i have a LOT of objects with children who are user control...  Is their a way to say to WPF to only tab stop on item who have a tabindex for a user control?

Comment: You could iterate all the controls in your window for all types qualify, check tabindex and set tabstop false if tabindex is maxvalue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is their a way to say to WPF to only tab stop on item who have a tabindex for a user control?

No, because `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex` is an attached property that has a default value of `Int32.MaxValue` unless you set it to something else for a specific element.

So there is no "only items who have a tabindex". You'll have to set the `TabStop` property to `false` for all items that you don't want to receive focus using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.

Comment: That will make my xaml horrible i have like thousand of element i don't want to stop on.

their is no better way to do it?

Comment: @Jebik: As mentioned, there is no way to use the absence a `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex` attribute in the XAML markup as a replacement for setting the `TabStop`property.

Comment: Ok i will try this then :') that's kinda sad microsoft didn't think of a NavigationType where if tabNavigation = MaxintValue then Tabstop = false.

Comment: `TabIndex` and `TabStop` are different properties used for different things.